# How do I move a text box in front of a listview control?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to allow a textbox to expand and cover other features on my form when a user clicks a button (the form itself has most of its real estate taken up so a second click of the button would contract the box to its former size)

I am running into an issue where the textbox will be covered up by a listview control no matter where I set the tab index (not sure if this changes the Z placement of features). Is there something else I can do to move the expanded textbox in front of the listview?

Comment: This seems to be an ActiveX control behaviour, like the ListView is. Only idea I have is to switch the ListViews visibility property on/off as you need it: `ListView0.Visible = Not ListView0.Visible`.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of that. Would tab index normally fix my issue if I wasn't trying to cover activeX controls?

Comment: The TAB-index is the order the controls will receive the focus when pressing `TAB`. Regarding the ActiveX behaviour I found that (old but similar problem): https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=680471

Comment: Overlapping controls is bad UI design.